# Android Client connecting to RestFul Webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services, client

hello All 
I have been fed up of looking for a simple example of rest webservice connecting to Android Application. I know so many people have asked this question before, but there are so many different answers as a theory.
I know I must use restful web-service, rather than SOAP for mobile applications. 
I need to create a webservice which is producing JSON, then in Android I can parse the JSON, but the problem is that as I am new to android I am looking for a simple example with both Server and client. 
A server : JAVA with Database connection and Restful WebService that produce JSON
Android Client : which parse the JSON result from the webservice

please if somebody can provide such a example , please please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, before you create your own web service, you might like to experiment with existing web services, such as those provided by Yahoo.

Have a look at the PlaceFinder API by Yahoo, its a free web service you can call, and is quite well documented. You can find the JSON examples [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/guide/examples.html)

Create a simple, standard java app that queries that web service, deals with JSON then System.out.print something from the response, that will get you familiar with what you need before you bring the android platform into the question

I haven't used the JSON examples, but I've written a [quick tutorial](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/tutorial-how-to-call-yahoo-rest-web-services-the-easy-way/) on the XML side which may be of help. Once you're comfortable with this, introduce that code into an Android application and get it to print something on the screen.

You have quite a broad set of requirements in your question, please try what I've recommended then come back with refined further questions

Good luck!